# onReceive not being called when setting an Alarm using Service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have been following a few tutorials to create an alarm, that when the onRecieve() method fires I use the TextToSpeech API to then speak. In doing this I discovered that I could not initalize the TextToSpeech when extending a BroadcastReciever, but found a tutorial that uses Service instead of BroadcastReciever.

The problem is that the onRecieve() method is never being called, and there are no errors being show to say that the alarm has not been set correctly.

Below is my method for setting an Alarm, in the MainActivity class.

```
protected void setAlarm() {

      Long time = timeTillAlarm;
      Log.v(TAG, "Time til Alarm = " + time);

    // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here we have
    // given AlarmReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when alarm triggers 
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the alarm for particular time
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);


}
```

Below is my AlarmReciever class:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
 private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";
 private TextToSpeech tts;
 private String spokenText;

 public AlarmReciever()
 {

 }

 public void onCreate() {
     tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
     spokenText = "Hello Kyle. Wake up now, it is a lovely day!";
     Log.v(TAG, "Alarm Text: " + spokenText);
     //speakOut();

 }

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {  
    Log.v(TAG, "Recieved Alarm"); 
    speakOut();
 }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

  @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {
      Log.v(TAG, "TTS Initialised");
         if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
             int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
             if (result != TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA && result != TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                // Log.v(TAG, "SPEAKING IN INIT");
                  //  tts.speak(spokenText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
             }
         }

     }

  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

  private void speakOut() {
        Log.v(TAG, "SPEAKING");
        tts.speak(spokenText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    } }
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Some things that might have gone wrong:

1. Have you declared the AlarmReceiver int the Android Manifest.xml? (is it spelled correctly?)
   `<receiver android:name=”path.to.package.AlarmReceiver”></receiver>`
2. Have you set a proper request code?
   That one cost me a few hours: When requesting your broadcast, you have to provide a request code. Altought I haven't found out its used yet, try setting it to any random number. e.g.

   > PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 564864421, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   When i had set it to 0, it did work in an example project (with only one activity and the alarm), but when I integrated it into the real deal (15 activities, services, etc.), it didn't work anymore. 
   The purpose of requestCode is explained [here](http://fatih-bulut.blogspot.co.at/2012/09/pendingintents-in-android.html).
3. Make sure your service is awake long enough:
   AlarmManager only calls onReceive, but does not acquire a wake lock - you have to deal with that on your own. I use the WakefulBroadcastReceiver here, because it does just that. If you use it (or wake locks), make sure, you have this in your manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Finally, here is my working example:

```
public class Alarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Alarm received");

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void setAlarm(Context context, long inMillis) {
        boolean alarmUp = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, Alarm.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
        if (alarmUp)
            Log.d("AlarmService", "Alarm is already up");
        else
            Log.d("AlarmService", "Alarm is NOT active");

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5468461, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+inMillis, alarmIntent);

        Log.d("AlarmService", "alarm set");
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
        Log.d("AlarmService", "alarm canceled");    
    }
}
```

with

```
<receiver android:name="path.to.Alarm" />
```